# Reading from Excel gives ####### in some columns

Tags: powershell

I am using powershell to read data from a .xls file. All goes well, no need to display the code. But I have an issue that I have no idea how to solve.

Some columns in the excel are not wide enough to display their data:

In reality:

```
2016.04.01
```

As the column is displayed when opening the file:

```
########
```

When I am reading from the excel, the cell content I get in powershell is actually `########`, **not** the actual cell content (= a date in this case).

I am reading 1000's of Excel files, all with the same issue. How can I fix this in my code? Is there a flag I need to set that I don't know about?

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Sounds as if you are using the Text property of the range object rather than the Value property?

Comment: Thanks! Noticed it myself just now. I am indeed using `$worksheet.cells.item(1,1).text + "blah"` but `$worksheet.cells.item(1,1).Value() + "blah"` gives me the error "Cannot convert value "|" to System.TimeSpan. Error: String was not recognized as valid TimeSpan"? In other words, I cannot concatenate to the cell content when using `Value` instead of `Text`?

Comment: I have no powershell experience whatsoever, so I can't really help you there. I expect you need to use some sort of date to string conversion?